# ActiveAdmin unknown attribute 'attribute' for Model for delegated method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm getting the error mentioned in the OP title when trying to save a model through ActiveAdmin despite delegating the attribute.
Specifically ,it's ActiveRecord that's throwing the error which happens here:

```
activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:59:in `rescue in _assign_attribute'
```

My model is:

```
class Hero  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :link, as: :linkable
  delegate :url, :section_id, :pdf, :path, to: :link, allow_nil: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :link, allow_destroy: true
end
```

And `Link` definitely has `section_id` on the model as I can see it in the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use delegate, it doesn't delegate the attribute rather, it delegates the method (correct me if I'm wrong),  which means you have to do it like this:

```
class Hero  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :link, as: :linkable
  delegate :url, :section_id,:section_id=, :pdf, :path, to: :link, allow_nil: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :link, allow_destroy: true
end
```

This worked for me.